# Java: Uncaught Exception Error?

Tags: java, uncaught-exception

I submitted this code to the KATTIS online code tester. It's supposed to return the difference of two numbers that have been given repeatedly until it reaches an EOF. It works just fine in eclipse, but KATTIS says that "An exception was not caught". I was hoping for some help as to what exception has not been caught.

The imports and class "Kattio" were provided so the input and output would always work with the online code system.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class Kattio extends PrintWriter {
    public Kattio(InputStream i) {
        super(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
    r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
    }
    public Kattio(InputStream i, OutputStream o) {
        super(new BufferedOutputStream(o));
        r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
    }

    public boolean hasMoreTokens() {
        return peekToken() != null;
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(nextToken());
    }

    private BufferedReader r;
    private String line;
    private StringTokenizer st;
    private String token;

    private String peekToken() {
    if (token == null) 
        try {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) return null;
            st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        }
        token = st.nextToken();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    return token;
    }

    private String nextToken() {
    String ans = peekToken();
    token = null;
    return ans;
    }
}

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kattio io = new Kattio(System.in, System.out);

        while (io.hasMoreTokens()){
            int n1 = io.getInt();
            int n2 = io.getInt();
            if (n1>n2){
                io.println(n1-n2);
            }
            else if (n2>n1){
                io.println(n2-n1);
            }
            else {
                io.println("0");
            }
        }
        io.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just a guess.

Look for exception in your code with different types of data. If a line with non integer your program will  terminate. It should probably look for next token?

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your main() by adding try/catch like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try { 
    Kattio io = new Kattio(System.in, System.out);

    while (io.hasMoreTokens()){
        int n1 = io.getInt();
        int n2 = io.getInt();
        if (n1>n2){
            io.println(n1-n2);
        }
        else if (n2>n1){
            io.println(n2-n1);
        }
        else {
            io.println("0");
        }
    }
    io.close();
} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Normally you would want more localized exception handling but this will at least **allow you to copy-paste us the stacktrace** so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the Kattis online code tester but assume it checks for unchecked exceptions that may be thrown (an uncaught checked exception would cause the code not to compile). I can't see anywhere in the code that checks that the next token is an Integer, so if Integer.parseInt tries to parse something which isn't an integer, it will throw a NumberFormatException.

Depending on the audience for your application, you could leave this as it is (if the audience is java developers who will understand that exception) or catch it rethrow something more user-friendly (if they are not).

```
public int getInt() {
         // not tested
         int nextInt;
         try {
              nextInt = Integer.parseInt(nextToken());
         } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Invalid number in file");
         }
         return nextInt;
}
```

Presumably though, the code tester would still complain though as it's throwing another (more user-friendly) exception :-)